# Raspberry pi Not booting after startup

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I have a Raspberry pi 4 with Raspbian OS installed. It was working fine but one day suddenly it stopped booting (without any changes). When connected to monitor, it would show the boot sequence -> rainbow screen -> black screen with no HDMI signal & I can't ssh into it.
I have tried:

1. changing power supply
2. Checked SD card. Could see boot & other data on windows using linuxreader

I can format SD card & reinstall OS as a last resort, but I have only 1 SD card & want to avoid setting up my microservices again.
Please help!!

Comment: BTW my Pi is always connected to LAN with static ip address configured at router.

Comment: Buy another sd card and use Pi Imager to flash the latest Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Just restore from your backup

Comment: @Milliways - but there were "no changes", so a backup wouldn't help 

Comment: Remove SD card - boot - what do you see now - do you have a USB drive - try booting from that

Comment: @JaromandaX if there were "no changes" the OP wouldn't need to set anything up again!